# Open save window in file path from cell and populate filename from cell

Tags: vba, excel

I need a simple code that will open the save window in a file location from a cell and also populate the file name from a cell, leaving the save window open so you can edit the path or filename before you click save if need be

I'm using this code but it only populates the filename

```
Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSaveAs).Show Range("A3").Text & "- (Submittal)" & ".xlsx"
```

I would like it to also open the save window in a file path from cell "A2"

[image]

Also i don't know if it matters but this will be ran on a workbook that has never been saved before

Comment: Prompt for filename and path via input box then use `workbooks.saveas`?

Answer (score 3):

This will get filename from Cell `A1` and Path from Cell `A2` both on `Sheet(1)`. Ensure that the path is in the format `C:\Users\name\` remembering to ensure there is a backslash `\` after the path.

```
Sub SaveAs()
Dim fPth As Object
Dim Path As String
Path = Sheets(1).Range("A2").Text
fileName = Sheets(1).Range("A1").Text
Set fPth = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)

        With fPth
            .InitialFileName = Path & fileName & ".xlsx"
            .Title = "Save your File"
            .InitialView = msoFileDialogViewList
            .Show
        End With

End Sub
```

Comment: This seems like it’s working but I can’t find the file that was saved from your code in the location it says i saved it in.

Comment: I'm not sure if i'm doing something wrong but when it saves let's say to the desktop the file never shows up on the desktop, but when i right click on excel it's under recent workbooks but it says its unavailable and may have been deleted